# I can't figured out how do I properly place the code block of "IF statement"

Tags: vb.net

All I want is to have the If statement code block properly be executed. Supposedly the idea was very simple. 
On the quantity portion:
 if it is not a number, it returns an error
else if it is a number which is above 0, message box "accepted"
else if the number is zero, then message box "quantity is 0"
else if the number is below zero, then message box "Error: quantity below zero"

However, when I try to run the program, when I try to input a number equals to RequestQuantity3TxtBx or below 0, it doesn't do anything at all.

```
If IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
    num1 = RequestQuantity2TxtBx.Text
    num2 = RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text
    total = num1 - num2
    RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text = total

    If RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text > 0 Then

        If RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text < 0 Then

            If RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Quantity = 0")
            Else
                '------if quantity below 0
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Quantity below 0")
            End If
        Else
            '------if quantity is equals to 1
            MessageBox.Show("Accepted")
        End If
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
End If
```

Comment: If you we're just commenting on my post just to insult me, that's totally fine,  cause that code block is just a partial, That code block is not just a test for a Textbox thing, I've intentionally omitted the true function as to why I have three options(0, <0, >0). I understand your point however, you have the worst attitude so far. I post that one cause I seek some help.

Comment: To all answer posters, `.IsNumeric` is left over from vb6. With .net we have `Integer.TryParse` Using the .net methods will allow you to move to other .net languages with understanding. So many examples are now written in C# that it is good to know the .net way. Also, I read that the .TryParse methods have speed improvements.

Comment: @Rael Please don't confuse instruction with insults. Usually the best teachers are concise and to the point. On another note, please turn on Option Strict. A TextBox's Text property is a String. A user can type anything into a text box and trying to do numerical comparisons with strings can lead to trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put some Validation in the TextBox to make sure that the user will enter a number instead of a character.

```
Private Sub RequestQuantityTxtBx_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RequestQuantityTxtBx.TextChanged
If Not IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
    MsgBox("This is not a number, please enter a number!")
End Sub

Private Sub RequestQuantity2TxtBx_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RequestQuantity2TxtBx.TextChanged
    If Not IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
        MsgBox("This is not a number, please enter a number!")
    End Sub
```

Then you can put the IF ELSE statement.

```
IF RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text > 0 THEN
    MsgBox("Accepted")
ELSEIF RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text = 0 THEN
    MsgBox("Quantity is 0")
ELSIF RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text < 0 THEN
    MsgBox("ERROR: Quantity below zero")
ELSE
    MsgBox("ERROR: It's not a number")
END IF
```

OR you can just replace your code with this.

```
If IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
    num2 = RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text
    IF IsNumeric(RequestQuantity2TxtBx.Text)
        num1 = RequestQuantity2TxtBx.Text
        total = num1 - num2
        RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text = total

        IF RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text > 0 THEN
            MsgBox("Accepted")
        ELSEIF RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text = 0 THEN
            MsgBox("Quantity is 0")
        ELSE RequestQuantity3TxtBx.Text < 0 THEN
            MsgBox("ERROR: Quantity below zero")
        END IF
    ELSE
            MsgBox("ERROR: It's not a number")
    END IF
ELSE
            MsgBox("ERROR: It's not a number")
END IF
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the right syntax that I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This code might be another option to full fill your requirement.

```
' Validate if the inputs are numeric
    If IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(RequestQuantityTxtBx2.Text) Then
        ' Cast the input to double to accomodate decimal input
        Dim num1 As Double = CType(RequestQuantityTxtBx.Text, Double)
        Dim num2 As Double = CType(RequestQuantityTxtBx2.Text, Double)

        ' Sum the input and assign the resul to the RequestQuantityTxtBx3
        Dim num3 As Double = num1 + num2
        RequestQuantityTxtBx3.Text = num3

        ' Perform validation to show appropriate message in the messagebox
        If num3 > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Accepted")
        ElseIf num3 = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Quantity is 0")
        ElseIf num3 < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Quantity below 0")
        End If
    Else
        ' Display error if the needed input is not numeric
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If
```

Hopefully it helps. Thanks.